# Legs twisting in rig

Tags: rigging

The legs on the mesh I'm trying to animate are twisted, no matter what pole angle I select.Here is the file : http://www.filedropper.com/potato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Backwards bend][image: Forward bend]

The rest position of the knees have a slight backwards bend to them, but they should instead have a forward bend.  Once the bend was added, zero-out the rolls on each bone to 0 degrees, and in the IK constraint settings, change the Pole Target angle on leg bottom.R to 0 degrees, and the leg bottom.L to 90 degrees.